# Segmentation fault - performSelectorOnMainThread on [NSFileManager defaultManager]

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, segmentation-fault, nszombie

This code seems to be causing a segmentation fault from time to time:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeItemAtPath:error:) withObject:filePath waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I want to perform all operations on files in the main thread to avoid conflicts like removing a file while the whole folder is iterated.

It produces this error:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x1084

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release
```

This is the stack trace of the crashed main thread:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x39fc8636 objc_msgSend + 22
1   Foundation                           0x30214c67 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 452
2   CoreFoundation                       0x2f7f6fef __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
3   CoreFoundation                       0x2f7f64b7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
4   CoreFoundation                       0x2f7f4ca7 __CFRunLoopRun + 628
5   CoreFoundation                       0x2f75f769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
6   CoreFoundation                       0x2f75f54b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
7   GraphicsServices                     0x346bc6d3 GSEventRunModal + 136
8   UIKit                                0x320be891 UIApplicationMain + 1134
9   Pocket3                              0x00050243 main (main.m:4)
10  libdyld.dylib                        0x3a4bcab7 start + 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

It looks like the NSFileManager is deallocated too early, but how can it be if it is a singleton?
Could it have something to do with the method [NSFileManager defaultManager] which is said to not be thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: new answer

`NSFileManager` is threadsafe (as long as you are not using its delegate, which you don't, and which you shouldnt do with the `-defaultManager` anyways). You can just call `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]` on whatever thread you are currently on. There is no advantage on doing it on the main thread only. In fact, performance will probably better if you update the filesystem in a background thread, because the UI will not block if the operation takes longer than expected.

### Old answer (why the crash did happen)...

The method `-removeItemAtPath:error:` wants two objects, but you are providing only one. So the second paramter (NSError **) that the `-removeItemAtPath:error:` method will see, is just some garbage that lies next to the `filePath` pointer in memory.

There is no version of `-performSelectorOnMainThread:...` that takes two objects. You may use `dispatch_sync` instead:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    if(!ok) {
         NSLog(@"an error happened: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This explanation makes a lot of sense. I will need a bit of time to confirm it solved the problem though, since the crash happens rarely. Thank you!

Comment: @rollkat the crash happens when the filemanager-method produces an error. When it returns `YES`, the item is just removed, there is no error, and the error pointer is not touched. You could replace `filePath` with `[@"P-" stringByAppendingString:filePath]` which will make the method always fail. The original approach with `-performSelector...` will always crash. The new approach with `dispatch_sync` will never crash, but just fail.

Comment: @rollkat furthermore, `NSFileManager` is threadsafe, as long as you are not using its delegate methods. So you could just call the `-removeItemAtPath:error:` method from whatever thread you are currently on, and it will just work!

Comment: correction: about me saying "will always crash": not always, but most of the time. in some cases, it will just corrupt memory, which will cause a crash maybe later.

Comment: The reason why I remove the file on the main thread is because it would crash if I iterate through the files in a directory in the main thread and simultaneously remove one file in this directory in another thread. I want to do all operations on those files in one same queue, it happens to be on the main thread but yes, it could be a background thread.

Comment: I eventually solved the problem in a simpler manner (I check if the file still exists inside the loop), but it's good to know anyways!

Comment: @rollkat "I check if the file still exists inside the loop" - that's maybe the best option here imho... but depending on how you implemented it there may be another possible race condition: if you say "if(file exists){data = read_from(file); handle(data)}" there is a race (the file could have been deleted between "file exists" and "read_from(file)"). if you do "data = read_from(file); if(data) { handle(data); }" it is save. btw you can use `-[NSData dataWithContentsFromFile:]`.